# How to get map of settings from application.yml?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caffeine-cache

Here is my application.yml config:

```
spring:
  cache:
    cache-names: all_config_bundle, all_config_dependence, config_plan
    caffeine.spec: maximumSize=100, expireAfterAccess=0s
    caches:
      all_config_bundle: maximumSize=100, expireAfterAccess=0s
      all_config_dependence: maximumSize=100, expireAfterAccess=0s
      config_plan: maximumSize=100, expireAfterAccess=0s
```

I need to group them, that's why I add another part of settings. Here is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CacheProperties.class)
@Setter
public class CacheConfig {

    private Map<String, String> caches;
}
```

`CacheProperties` already has a `"spring.cache"` prefix, so I only added a name of my group.
I still get "null" in my map. What is my mistake?

Comment: have you tried adding `spring.cache` as prefix on this class as well ?

Comment: @Deadpool Yes, it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [@ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html) and `prefix` it works for me

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.cache")
@Data
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {

     private Map<String, String> caches;
}
```

**Output :**

```
{all_config_bundle=maximumSize=100, expireAfterAccess=0s, all_config_dependence=maximumSize=100, expireAfterAccess=0s, config_plan=maximumSize=100, expireAfterAccess=0s}
```